# Redirect all subdirectories a level up with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This question can be asked before but I cannot find the solution. I would like to redirect all subdirectories a level up with htaccess. See my example urls below.

```
OLD URL                         NEW URL
/vacation-countryONE/hotspots   /vacation-countryONE
/vacation-countryONE/culture    /vacation-countryONE

/vacation-countryTWO/hotspots   /vacation-countryTWO
/vacation-countryTWO/culture    /vacation-countryTWO
```

What htaccess rule should I use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/vacation-([^/]+)/.+ /vacation-$1
```

Or if you've got rewrite rules already, add this before your rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^vacation-([^/]+)/.+ /vacation-$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NE,R=302]
```